# How do I test for equality between an Array of associations and an Object (instance) in Pharo Smalltalk?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I have this small piece of code which doesn't seem to work and test weather the objects are one and the same.

```
something := ((selectedTab value) ==  registerObject).
```

**or:**

```
((selectedTab value) ==  registerObject) ifTrue: [ "this never get's executed" ]
```

I've "Explored pointer" on both instances "selected value" has the exact same id as "registerObject" and I've even put in parenthesis to boot.

Can anyone enlighten me on the subject?

Comment: The second case is baffling, but I'm not exactly sure what you mean by codeSnippet1 or: codeSnippet2. Do you mean neither works? The first one depends on how #= is defined and could be a different issue, even though it is defined as equivalent to #== by default.

Comment: With "id" you mean `#identityHash`? If so, then `#==` *must* answer true. That's the VM implementation (in Pharo). Which VM / image versions did you try this with?

Comment: Edited the question. Both code snippets use "==" (trying to see if the object in the  is one and the same with another object) one tries to store true or false into a variable and the other should just evaluate and execute the block. If I use a breakpoint on the method something is always "nil" and the block never executes. Maybe I'm doing something else wrong?

Comment: Oh god, finally figured it out, selectedTab was an Array or 'name' -> object associations with just one such association.

I had to use 'selectedTab first value'

Comment: Np, maybe delete the question?

Comment: @SeanDeNigris Edited the title so it doesn't read as Pharo having a problem with something like this. But I'll leave it here for other googlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SelectedTab was an Array or 'name' -> object associations with just one such association. I was convinced it was storing just the object itself.

I had to use **first value** instead of just **value**:

```
something := ((selectedTab first value) ==  registerObject).

((selectedTab first value) ==  registerObject) ifTrue: [ "this never get's executed" ]
```

Rookie mistake everyone!!! I raised hell for nothing.